# FFMPEG caching how to configure and get cache file names

Tags: c#, caching, ffmpeg

I am using a c# WPF video player wrapper that uses FFMPEG. It is called FFME MediaElement. Using this i have been able to activate caching in FFMPEG using the "cache" https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#cache protocol value.
This works and i can see the cache files being created in my application directory as video files are loaded. It seems to create a new cache file each time a video is loaded. The cache file names are of the convention ffcachexxxxxx.

Ignoring the wrapper i am using, is there a way (if i was using FFMPEG on its own) to get or determine the cache file name, or get FFMPEG to auto delete the cache file. After a while the cache files take a lot of room and i would like a way to purge them. If there is a way to do this in FFMPEG then i could apply that to the wrapper i am using.

So im looking for any of
1. a way to get the current cache file name so i can delete on video close
2. a setting to make FFMPEG auto delete cached files.
3. a setting to FFMPEG to purge all stored cache files in one go.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: ffmpeg does not clean up temp files. I've submitted a patch to print the names of temp files that ffmpeg generates. Will post answer when it is upstreamed.

Comment: Would this be some kind of text file that is created in real time storing the cache temp file names as they are created ? Or could you explain when you say print, print to what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg does auto-delete cache files but due to a quirk on Windows, they weren't getting deleted. Fixed now. Upgrade to latest ffmpeg git build tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks very much for that. I use FFMPEG builds from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/  how can i tell when this fix is available in a release build as opposed to a nightly GIT build ?

Comment: It will be in ver 4.2, which will be released in a week or two.